# Java class error Main.java:3: error:

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I keep getting this error message I have checked my file names, and my public class is the same as my .java file. Besides checking that I have no idea where to go.

```
Main.java:3: error: class ClassGenderPercentages is public, should be    declared in a file named ClassGenderPercentages.java
public class ClassGenderPercentages
   ^
```

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassGenderPercentages

{
public static void main (String args[])
{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int maleStudents, femaleStudents;
    int totalStudents;
    double maleStudentPercentage, femaleStudentPercentage;

    maleStudents = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of male registered:" + maleStudents);

    femaleStudents = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of female registered:" + femaleStudents);


    totalStudents = (int) (maleStudents + femaleStudents);
    maleStudentPercentage = ((100 * maleStudents) / totalStudents);
    femaleStudentPercentage = ((100 * femaleStudents) / totalStudents);



    System.out.println("The percentage of males registered is: " + maleStudentPercentage + "%");
    System.out.println("The percentage of females registed is: " + femaleStudentPercentage + "%");
 }
}
```

Comment: The error clearly says that the file name should be ClassGenderPercentages.java, while your file is named Main.java

Answer (score 0):

Your files is named Main.java, your class ClassGenderPercentages.
You can rename your file to ClassGenderPercentages.java
(that is already said in the error you received from the compiler)